# Keeping GoogleDrive files in sync with local files

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I'm integrating Google Drive into an iOS app with the SDK, (which works great, thank you) and I would like to keep a set of files on Google Drive in sync with files on the device.  By this I mean: When a user renames or moves a file on their device, I'd like it to rename/move on the server.  If a user renames a folder, I'd like to rename that folder on the server.

With other cloud services that use a path to identify files, I can generate the path to rename or move the files on the server whenever I need them.  With Google Drive, this is not the case--I need a file ID to rename or move something.  Is there a convenient way to get the file ID from a path?  Will I have to store information from Google Drive in my app?  Is there a recommended best practice for this situation?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, you can keep a list of file ID when initially you insert file into Google Drive. When you insert a file into Google Drive, it will return a file resource which contains the inserted file ID and it doesnt change unless you delete it.

Comment: This is true, and how I was thinking of doing it, but then I'd have to add a bit of data to all my local files just for Google Drive.  I'd prefer to keep it simpler, and not hold on to service specific data, if possible.  But this solution may end up being necessary?